# read contents of a file and display it on browser

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use flask to achieve the following.

I have a file on my local disk.. Its a big file.. So I just want to read top 20 lines of that file.

How do I read files and display its contents on the brower?

Any pointers.. suggestions. 
Thanks

Comment: well you can pretty continuously read the top 20 lines of the python file... with open("file", 'r') as f: f.readlines[:20]

Comment: do you want to open a new browser window for displaying the top 20 lines of that file?

Comment: @VirendraRajput: Yes.... that would be sweet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, should work

```
import webbrowser

# firstly you need to make write to an html file that will have the top 20 lines 
# you can do that using 

top_lines_file = open("shows.html", "w")
i = 1
while i in range(1,21):
    top_lines_file.write("write something to the file")
    i += 1
    # this will iterate over the file and write to it 20 times
top_lines_file.close() # close the file

# now you need to pass the path of the html file to the webbrowser object
webbrowser.open("file://" + path/to/the/html/file) 
# this will open the webbrowser with your html file
```